# How can the Sitecore search API be extended to support Azure search traffic analytics?

Tags: content-search, sitecore-api, azure-search

I'm experimenting with adding support for conditionally returning `SearchId` for Azure search traffic analytics purposes (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-traffic-analytics) as part of Azure search queries made by the Sitecore content search API. Doing so involves passing a custom header to the Azure search service along with the query.

Ideally, this would be something that is conditionally available, say, on the search context object and, if set, the `SearchId` property would be hydrated on each search result object. Something like this:

```
...
ctx.IncludeSearchId = true;
...
var results = ctx.GetQueryable<FooResult>();
...
var searchId = oneFooResult.SearchId; // e.g. "9acc737d-cf2e-4b4f-8b4f-d70288ce4e77"
```

I'm only about a third of the way there. I've implemented a custom search service client inheriting from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient` and am overriding the `Search(SearchRequest searchRequest)` method to *always* pass the custom `"x-ms-azs-return-searchid"` header. The custom search service client is patched in by switching the `"type"` attribute on the `<searchServiceClient />` node from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure` to my custom type. I get a response header containing the `SearchId`, as expected.

[image: Getting a valid SearchId]

I'm still missing two key things:

1. The ability to set a flag on the search context to *conditionally* pass the `"x-ms-azs-return-searchid"` header with the query (likely by inheriting from `CloudSearchSearchContext` and adding a flag property and eventually adding a custom flag property to the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Model.SearchRequest` object around which to build an `if`).
2. Mapping the `SearchId` value to a property on each result object to allow the caller to use the property downstream (to push analytics data into Application Insights when results are "clicked").

I don't see an elegant way of adding support Azure search traffic analytics that *doesn't* involve replacing/copying large swaths of the Sitecore search API.

What is the "correct" way to do something like this? Perhaps it's better to open a Sitecore support ticket and let them tell me?